# Serial Console Driver as a Loadable Module

Tags: drivers

Can a linux 2.6 serial console driver that registers itself using the console_initcall() macro be developed as a loadable module or must it be compiled in-kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [in the kernel documentation](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/console/console.txt;h=926cf1b5e63ebe7d3d597168c5c3042174c5bcb7;hb=HEAD) there needs to be a system console driver which is called during the [initialization phase](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=init/main.c;h=ff49a6dacfbbdf673e38f4797127c5e4b8de8c73;hb=HEAD#l571).

So if you want default system console support for the serial drivers, you need to have them in-kernel. See [drivers/tty/serial/Kconfig](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=drivers/tty/serial/Kconfig;h=2de99248dfaee06329f8a4f49505c9db66f7adf1;hb=HEAD) for the existing drivers.

[This discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/linuxppc-dev@lists.ozlabs.org/msg56881.html) might be also interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

serial console module can be initialize also inside the UART driver also if UART supports serial console then UART driver structure's <kbd>cons</kbd> field would be pointing to serial console.